# htaccess file and how to change permission's in it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

I have created a new folder `example` inside `/var/www/html/` to run some php code. But when I try to access the files via `localhost/example` it is showing-

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

The other files in the `/var/www/html` folder like `localhost/welcome.php` are still working. I also changed permission of the files. Should I create htaccess file and if so where? In general what is the process of creating a new project/folder to run php and it's relation to htaccess? A link for in-depth explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: We can't tell you whether you _should_ create a configuration file (".htaccess"). That depends on what you are trying to do, which you did not really say. We can give you a hint to the actual error message, however: it is crystal clear: the http server process is unable to read that file. That is a question of file system permissions. So I suggest you tripple check the permissions of that file and the folder it is placed in. Add those details to the question if you are unsure. Remember that the http server is operated under a specific system user account...

Comment: There was a permission issue only. The permission should have been given to www-data . I have resolved it now. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Usually one assigns such a file to the _group_ the http server process is operated as (usually "www-data" on debian based systems or something like "apache2" on many other distributions). Note: the group, not the user. This allows to assign group read access while keeping personal write access to your own account. So something like `-rw-r---- 1 fred www-data  389 Mar 08 .htaccess`...